# Appwrite phonenumber password login

Tags: flutter, authentication, appwrite

I am new to app development but wanted to start with flutter and appwrite. I want to build an app with Appwrite and Flutter. This app should have a restricted area were only registered users should have access.

I want to use a modified email/password authentication, with a phone number instead of the email.

I know how I can create a user with a phone number and confirm this number using the send secret. But I could not find anythig to get a session with only phone number and password.

Is my desired behavoir even possible with appwrite or am I just missing something?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, phone and password authentication is not supported. You can hack a workaround for this by using the email and password where the email is `<phone number>@fakedomain.com`.

What's your reason for not using Appwrite's Phone Auth system?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew the workaround already, I thought there is another way because it is possible that i might add email + password registration later. I do not want my users to verify everytime with their phone number, so i thought i could avoid that with a password. Can phone sessions be extended so as long as the user doesnt use a logout option i can extend the session?

Comment: By default, Appwrite sessions last 1 year. There is no way to refresh the session outside of that.

Comment: Okay thanks! Is there some reason why one can't refresh this token?

Comment: Probably because sessions last a year so there isn't a big need for refreshing.

Comment: But would'nt it be convenient to just keep the user logged in while he uses the app? Threrefore a refresh without the user having to authenticate himself again would be nice.